# 400 Bad Request Error on POST request with Flask

Tags: python, forms, flask, bad-request

I am attempting to return data from a HTML form with a POST request using Flask. For some reason I get a 400 Bad Request error. Looking at Chrome Dev Tools, I can see that all of the form fields with the input tag are part of the post request. The select tag with the dropwdown list is not being captured and I think this is creating the error. Anyone know why the select tag is not being captured in the post request? Any help much appreciated.

Here is the HTML form:

```
        <label for="vendor">Select Vendor</label>
        <div class="flextable p-b" style="padd">
          <div class="flextable-item">     
            <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" form="addInvoice" name="vendor" id="vendor">
              <option>Jack Jaffa & Associates</option>
              <option>Jacobs/Doland/Beer LLC</option>
              <option>Jenkins & Huntington Inc.</option>
              <option>Joseph J. Blake & Associates, Inc.</option>
              <option>Langan (Geotechnical)</option>
              <option>Madison Realty Capital</option>
              <option>McNamara Salvia, Inc</option>
              <option>Metropolis Group, Inc</option>
              <option>National Grid</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="flextable-item">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary-outline">Add vendor</button>
          </div>


        <label for="invoice_number">Invoice Number:</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control p-b" placeholder="Every vendor invoice # must be unique" name="invoice_number" id="invoice_number">

         <label for="invoice_amount">Amount:</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control p-b" placeholder="$0.00" name="invoice_amount" id="invoice_amount">

         <label for="invoice_amount">Description:</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control p-b" placeholder="$0.00" width="100%" name="description" id="description">

      <div class="spacer"></div>



      <div class="flextable">
        <div class="flextable-item">
          <label for="date_received">Date received:</label>
         </div>
        <div>
          <div class="flextable-item">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
              <span class="icon icon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
            <input type="text" value="01/01/2015" class="form-control" data-provide="datepicker" style="width: 200px;" name="date_received" id="date_received">
          </div>
            </div>
              </div>
                </div>
        </div>


        <div class="modal-actions p-t-lg">
          <button type="button" class="btn-link modal-action" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn-link modal-action" id="submit" >
            <strong>Save + Continue</strong>
          </button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Here is the Flask python route:

```
@app.route('/add_invoice', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_invoice():
""" Method for capturing form data to add invoice items to database"""

if request.method == 'POST':
    find_cost_code = 7777  # eventually need code to lookup cost-code from POST request
    print request.form['invoice_number']
    print request.form['invoice_amount']
    print request.form['description']
    print request.form['vendor']
    print request.form['date_received']


return "This is a test"
```

ADDED INFO:
So if I remove this line, the bad request error goes away:

```
print request.form['vendor']
```

This is because the "vendor" field is the only one in the html form that uses a select tag for input and that data is not catpured in the post request dictionary (which i can see in Chrome Dev Tool). The POST request is missing the field associated with the select tag. Not sure how to capture the select tag in the form data...

Answer (score 3):

I've faced this issue many time when dealing with flask form, I think the solution is to enable csrf token protection :
according to [this](http://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/csrf.html) you need to initialise and enable it for you app!
Most of time error 400 is due to missing CSRF token.
you can do it as :

```
from flask_wtf.csrf import CSRFProtect

csrf = CSRFProtect(app)
```

for initialisation
and in your form add:

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
```

hope it will help!!
feel free to edit.

Comment: Apologies, in my excitement, I forgot.

Answer (score 1):

form="addInvoice"

This attribute as part of my HTML form markup was what caused the error. I'm not sure exactly why but when it is removed, the error goes away.

(Thanks for your help above in trying to look into this.)

Comment: The `form="addInvoice"` make the field be sent with form `addInvoice`. In this case, it does not exist, but this is the reason the field wasn't sent.

Answer (score -2):

You need [getlist](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict.getlist) to capture `select`.